# Does withColumn lead to collecting results on the driver

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions, parquet

I am performing some operations on a pyspark dataframe using UDFs

Following are the operations:

```py
df.repartition(16).withColumn(
    'data',
    explode(udf('col1','col2'))
).write.mode('overwrite').parquet('result.parquet')
```

Does any of the above result in bringing the results of the udf on the driver?
Which operations from above involve data transfer?
Will the executor nodes save their individual parquet files ?

Comment: `withColumn` is not an action. it will only create a projection that is resolved in the upcoming action

Comment: @samkart will the executor nodes save the parquet for their partition only or results are bought back to the driver for writing to parquet?

Comment: everything is on worker side